# Django not searching templates directory defined in APP_DIRS setings

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I got a templates directory in same level as my project directory so I put in settings.py

```
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
'APP_DIRS': True,
```

but Django is not searching templates in apps it stops at DIRS

all apps needed are installed

Comment: Same issue here.  No solution!!!

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to put the app name at the end of INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts'  # <= put your app name here i guess?
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this today (I'm on django 2.1). Solution was to add 'myappname' to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings (something you used to have to do on older django versions, but I thought was not mandatory anymore). Without doing this, django template processors were not looking to myappname/templates/myappname/

I also have the TEMPLATES_DIRS set up like some other answers, but for whatever reason that was not sufficient on my current setup (I broke my laptop, so I am django-ing on windows w brand new python 3.7 and brand new django 2.1 (didn't have to do this step the last time I worked w/ django about a week ago...)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `DIRS` setting. It should include templates directory itself.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

        # True or False, depends on your case.
        'APP_DIRS': True,

        # Default django setup.
        'OPTIONS': { 
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Double check your code. The solution works just fine.

Comment: I'm updating my question it's app_dirs which is true that is not being traversed.

Comment: Django prints a list of inspected folders. Take a look at the error page, there should be a section **Template-loader postmortem**. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name of the template directory under the TEMPLATES array in the 'DIRS' section in your settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['your folder name'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'logyt_transporte.context_processors.module_variables',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: why not? DIRS is an array and you can put more directory names in there. I don't think there's any other way, I searched for this answer a while ago.

Comment: I'm updating my question it's app_dirs which is true that isnot being traversed.

Comment: Not only not scalable, but also hardcoding.

Comment: you can always use os.path.join as stated in the above answer, but the way to make things work is just the same. Writing the required folder in the DIRS array. @user7410898 are your template folders following the default notation?? modulename/templates/modulename/file.html???

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to override templates from a third-party package.

My issue was that I had `INSTALLED_APPS` in the following order:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # core
    # third-party
    # mine
]
```

Because I clearly glossed over the documentation which tells you this is not how it works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps

Specifically the last line:

> When several applications provide different versions of the same
> resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the
> application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence.

Treat it like fallback order and ensure the overrides are *before* the originals, *et voila*. Sigh.